# Printing from Ubuntu to Windows printer

Tags: 13.04, windows, printing

I have a Windows Vista machine downstairs with 2 printers hooked up to it (it's currently not possible to connect them to my ubuntu machine).  I have printer sharing enabled as well as discovery enabled on the Vista machine, and I'm able to find/print from other windows machines in my house with no issue.

I can't do that with my Ubuntu machine though, and I have not seen any guides online on how to do so, it's usually a ubuntu 'printer server' in all the cases.

I've tried finding the printers with the printer settings by both SAMBA and the IP address assigned by my router to the Vista machine.

So I'm just going to ask for a direction in how to go about doing this.

Comment: Hi, This page may be worth a look: [NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu)

Comment: You also need to make sure printer sharing is enable in the Network ans Sharing Center.

Comment: Doesn't help, as the feature I'm trying to do is EMPTY in that list (Windows Printer Server).

Answer (score 0):

Is there a Windows (or other) Firewall on your Vista machine? Have you opened port 631 on that machine to the IP of the Linux machine? If not, try that. CUPS uses port 631 by default for communication so you should also verify that your Firewall on the Linux machine also allows for port 631 communication. If it does not from the machine listed, that too, could cause the non-discoverable printer issue.

Hope that helps put you on the right path. It is truly easy once discovered.